# What encoding can be used for JIS X 0201 (and other) encoding or decoding in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, character-encoding, hl7-v2

Out of the [list of supported encoding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0#list-of-encodings) for C#, which of those will and will not support encoding or decoding the character sets listed [here](https://hl7-definition.caristix.com/v2/HL7v2.7/Tables/0211).

I am looking for a mapping, something like the below table (the below example could be wrong it's just an example).

| HL7 Alt Character Set | Supported? | C# Encoding |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ASCII | Yes | us-ascii |
| 8859/1 | Yes | iso-8859-1 |
| ISO IR14 | No |  |

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_JIS ? [JIS X 0201 was supplanted by subsequent encodings such as Shift JIS (which combines this standard and JIS X 0208)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JIS_X_0201).

Comment: @JosefZ does that mean you can use shift_jis as a direct replacement for 0201, 0208 etc and its backward compatible?